# Reset Tcl_NewObj in a loop

Tags: c, tcl

My goal is to do a list but in C, with the help of Tcl API.
*Tcl* loop :

```
set listObj {}
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    set data {}
    lappend data int $i
    lappend listObj $data
}
# result : {{int 0} {int 1} {int 2} {int 3} {int 4} {int 5} {int 6} {int 7} {int 8} {int 9}}
```

*C* loop :

```
Tcl_Obj *listObj = Tcl_NewListObj (0,NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Tcl_Obj* data = Tcl_NewObj();

    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, data, Tcl_NewStringObj("int", 3));
    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, data, Tcl_NewIntObj(i)); 

    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, listObj, data);
    
}
```

It works as expected, but I don't know if `data` in C code if properly used. In Tcl to reset my variable I'm using this `{}`.
My question : What’s the way to reset a `Tcl_Obj` properly with the help of Tcl API ?

Comment: That C code compiles for you? `Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, data, i);` should be something like `Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, data, Tcl_NewIntObj(i));`

Comment: @Shawn you are right, I edit my question.

Comment: Looks fine now.

Comment: OT, but still: Why not reducing to `lappend listObj [list "int" $i]`. The variable `data` is not necessary, and does not add to readability, or similar.

Comment: @mrcalvin, Yes I know in `Tcl`, but in `C` I don't know how to do... your syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine. The `data` variable is just a pointer to a Tcl_Obj. When it is initially created using Tcl_NewObj(), that Tcl_Obj has a refCount of 0. By appending it to listObj, Tcl_ListObjAppendElement() will increment the refCount to 1. At that moment, the Tcl_Obj is effectively handed off to the listObj list.

If you want to be pedantic, you can use `Tcl_IncrRefCount(data)` after creating the new Tcl_Obj, and use `Tcl_DecrRefCount(data)` to relinquish your claim to it. That would explicitly reset your variable. But since your code does nothing that risks releasing the variable prematurely, you may safely omit those two calls.

Comment: Being able to avoid a lot of explicit refcount management in simple cases like this one is exactly why refcounts start at 0.